# Savings in Germany (Munich) or in Norway (Oslo)

Tags: germany, taxes, salary, norway, cost-of-living

Which is better option for a married person (NON-EU resident) seeking good in hand savings (after tax), residence benefits, healthcare and balanced and quality life?

a) salary of EUR 69,000/- year in Munich Germany

b) salary of NOK 710,400 year in Oslo, Norway

P.S - Main aim is how much money saved after tax and after incurring monthly expenses like cost of living (accommodation, transit/commute, food, etc)

Answer (score 3):

This really depends.

Taxes are lower in Germany but Munich has become very expensive to live in, even compared to Oslo. However, Norway includes its health insurance and better pension benefits in its taxes which come on top in Germany.

Oslo is much smaller than Munich, therefore commutes are typically shorter but this depends on where you would live and where your job is located. Work hours are shorter in Norway and tend to be more flexible.

Both countries provide free schools but if your partner wants to work, Norway offers better opportunities, especially with children in kindergarten age as Norway is very layed out for two income families. If your partner is not intending to work, Germany is probably more friendly with its tax system whereas surviving on one income can be very difficult in Norway.

Health care is of high standard in both countries.

I lived in both cities and chose Norway, partly because me and my partner both want to work full time. But either city is a great place to live.

Comment: [Numbeo](https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/compare_cities.jsp?country1=Germany&country2=Norway&city1=Munich&city2=Oslo&tracking=getDispatchComparison) says Munich is quite a bit cheaper.

Comment: It really depends, restaurants, taxis and alcohol are indeed cheaper in Munich but at least by my experience, this does not make too much of my budget. I comare my spending, though.

Comment: Some, but as listed, if you have three kids in kindergarten and do not spend your nights out in town, this calculation gets very relative.

Comment: I lived in Munich and now live in Oslo, both for many years, I simply don't see how these numbers are accurate. But yes, if you spend all your time in bars and restaurants, Oslo is not your town.